# Display Percent of characters

Tags: mysql

How do I display some percent of characters of my data. Suppose I need to display 50% of characters of the name such as "Lecturer".

I was asked this question i exam which i failed to do so.

```
create table employee(
e_id int(10) , 
empname char(10),
designation char(10),
salary int(10),
age int(10),
deptid int(10),
job varchar(30));

insert into employee values(101,'Hassan','TA',46000,20,10,"manager");
insert into employee values(102,'Tahir','Poem',43000,45,10,"manager");
insert into employee values(103,'Ahmed','Hand',36000,27,20,"Analyst");
insert into employee values(104,'Imran','lecturer',24000,27,30,"Manager");
insert into employee values(105,'Furqan','teacher',36000,22,30,"Salesman");

select empname 
from employee 
where length(empname/2);
```

while trying I get the full name of employees instead of half characters of their name.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LEFT()` and `LENGTH()` it is possible:

```
SELECT LEFT(empname, LENGTH(empname)/2)
FROM employee
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help,

`50` is your percentage. you can change the percentage whatever you want.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(empname, 1, ROUND( (length(empname)/100) * 50 ) ) AS ExtractString from employee
```

Comment: Using `ROUND()` is not really needed as it seams that `SUBSTRING()` in MySQL automatically "rounds" see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTBjPmJ5VqbBYoPDcUQgQX/1) ..

Comment: Both are working , only the difference is, the first one will give you only the 50%'s result, in second one, you can change the percentage whatever you want